# 403 Error - Amazon S3 & Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

When trying to `collectstatic` on my heroku server, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 168, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 107, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 305, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 218, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 414, in exists
    return k.exists()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 539, in exists
    return bool(self.bucket.lookup(self.name, headers=headers))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 142, in lookup
    return self.get_key(key_name, headers=headers)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 192, in get_key
    key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 230, in _get_key_internal
    response.status, response.reason, '')
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

In my IAM user policies, I have AmazonS3FullAccess added to the user.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: First things first: 1- are you able to view the site (with broken static files) ?
2- Are in DEBUG ?

Comment: @radev I can view the site (with broken static files), and no, I am not in DEBUG.